# Where clause to include and exclude sql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables where I am selecting values and then filtering them so that:

1. `BookId` would be 11 or 12
2. `C.Id` is not 5515, 7582, 7648
3. `C.Id` can be 5967 , but if `D.part` is equal to 8, then do not inlude row which has `C.Id=5967 and D.part = 8`

This is my select:

```
select * from dbo.C c
cross join dbo.D d 
where
c.Id = d.Id 
AND (c.BookId = 11 or c.BookId = 12) -- BookId is 11 or 12
and (c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648) -- 5515, 7582, 7648 (do not include)
or (c.Id = 5967 AND d.part <> 8)) -- include 5967 but not with part = 8
```

it all works fine except the last line `(c.Id = 5967 AND d.part <> 8), I still see this row in my results. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret the sentence: "D.part is equal to 8, then do not include row which has C.Id=5967" as:

```
(D.part = 8) => (C.Id <> 5967)
```

This is logically equivalent with:

```
NOT (D.part = 8) OR (C.Id <> 5967)
(D.part <> 8) OR (C.Id <> 5967)
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
NOT (D.part = 8 AND C.Id = 5967)
```

Your complete query would then be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.C c
CROSS JOIN dbo.D d 
WHERE c.Id = d.Id 
AND (c.BookId = 11 or c.BookId = 12) -- BookId is 11 or 12
AND (c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648) -- 5515, 7582, 7648 (do not include)
AND NOT (D.part = 8 AND C.Id = 5967) -- include 5967 but not with part = 8
```

I would suggest rewriting the query with a JOIN instead of CARTESIAN PRODUCT

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.C c
JOIN dbo.D d 
    ON c.Id = d.Id 
WHERE (c.BookId = 11 or c.BookId = 12) -- BookId is 11 or 12
AND (c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648) -- 5515, 7582, 7648 (do not include)
AND NOT (D.part = 8 AND C.Id = 5967) -- include 5967 but not with part = 8
```

Answer (score 3):

With this specific part of the condition:

```
(c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648)  or  (c.Id = 5967 AND d.part <> 8))
```

a row where `c.Id` is 5967 and `d.part` 8 will be evaluated like this

```
(c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648)  or  (c.Id = 5967 AND d.part <> 8))
                 ↓                                 ↓
               true              or              false         →      true
```

So you can see why this row would be returned.

I can see more than one way to change your condition.  Here is one option:

```
c.Id = d.Id 
AND (c.BookId = 11 or c.BookId = 12) -- BookId is 11 or 12
and (c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648)) -- 5515, 7582, 7648 (do not include)
and (c.Id <> 5967 or d.part <> 8) -- exclude 5967 too unless part <> 8
```

Here is another:

```
c.Id = d.Id 
AND (c.BookId = 11 or c.BookId = 12) -- BookId is 11 or 12
and (c.Id not in (5515, 7582, 7648, 5967) -- 5515, 7582, 7648, 5967 (do not include)
  or (c.Id = 5967 and d.part <> 8)) -- include 5967 but not with part = 8
```

The second one is almost identical to yours.  The only difference is that 5967 is included in the `in` list.  It might seem redundant to list the same value in multiple predicates, though the way the logic is expressed I believe it is perfectly fine.  Still, the first option has no such repetition in case that is your preference, and the results produced would be the same.

On a different note, please consider taking full advantage of the explicit `JOIN` syntax to separate different kinds of conditions.  The `c.Id = d.Id` part is a *joining* condition while the others are *filtering* conditions.  A joining condition would make most sense in the `ON` clause.  So instead of `CROSS JOIN ... WHERE <joining_condition>`, use `INNER JOIN ... ON <joining_condition>`, like this:

```
select *
from dbo.C c
inner join dbo.D d on c.Id = d.Id  -- joining condition, moved from WHERE
where  -- filtering conditions go here
(c.BookId = 11 or c.BookId = 12) -- BookId is 11 or 12
and ... /* the rest of the conditions */
```